# How do I convert the screen's resolution to a usable variable?

Tags: android, size

All right, so I'm making a game for Android.
For the menu screen, I want to have the logo floating in the background, from right to left and vice versa. That doesn't seem too much of an issue, but I want it to be at random heights, and not out of the screen, so I'll need the resolution. I found the following script in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int scrHeight = size.y;
```

Unfortunately, I get an error in line 3:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token "size", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

I don't know what's wrong (I basically ctrl+c,ctrl+v'd it), and I feel kind of reluctant to use getHeight() since it's deprecated...

And then one tiny extra question: getSize was implemented in SDK 13, right? Does that mean it doesn't work on phones released before SDK 13, or is that something I can ignore?

Thanks already!

Comment: Look at the last comment on the accepted answer for the question you link to, that has a solution for pre and post API 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're right, this method won't work on pre AP13. You have to use `display.getWidth()`; and `display.getHeight()`; before API13.

Comment: Yup, this works. Is there also a way to get it in density pixels instead of normal pixels?

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting devices less than API level 13, then you'll have to make do with `getHeight()`. Using `getSize()` won't compile in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(
    Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

int srcWidth = display.getWidth();
int srcHeight = display.getHeight();
```